# how to add strings to the string.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, string

hi guys i have lots of public strings in one of my classes like these below.

```
public String HeadlightString = "lights not satisfactory", 
ReflectorString = "Reflectors and warning devices not satisfactory",
HornString = "Horn and other warnings not satisfactory", 
MirrorsString = "Mirrors not satisfactory", 
BrakessystemStrings = "Problem with the brakes System";
```

how can i add them to my string.xml then call them to my class. this would really help to tidy my code.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html
Have you checked this??

Comment: [String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) Read this carefully. You can find all answers here regarding your question

Comment: no i hadnt seen that thanks @Rahil2952

Comment: Simply open your `strings.xml` file and add your new strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them like that to your `strings.xml`

```
<string name="HeadlightString">lights not satisfactory</string>
```

And then you can get it by calling in your `Activity` or `Fragment` or any other class which has a `Context` reference

```
String headlightString = getString(R.string.HeadlightString);
```